# Xamarin.Forms Android Startup takes 10 seconds

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My Android app (created using Xamarin.Forms) takes around 10 seconds to start (both in Debug & Release mode) on a real device (Asus Zenfone 2). The splash screen is showing for 8 seconds. Here is my log attached where as "extrony" is my app name. Only assembly loading takes this much time. Any help?

[Android Startup log](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AtqzJj-X1OCRhoR9fzT9jQkK_hwQcQ)

**EDIT 1:**
It actually takes 10 seconds (I mentioned 8 by mistake, but updated now)

**EDIT 2:** On an Emulator (I am using Android Emulator for Visual Studio) the app starts faster i.e. within 4.3seconds. However on my real device (Asus Zenfone2), the time it takes is 10seconds. Here is additional thing I see on the debug output while debugging on a real device (It doesn't appear if you debug on the emulator) and loading these assemblies ALONE takes ~6seconds.

```
Android application is debugging.
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/extrony.Droid.dll
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Acr.Support.Android.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Acr.UserDialogs.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Acr.UserDialogs.Interface.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/AndHUD.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Android.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/FFImageLoading.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/FFImageLoading.Forms.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/FFImageLoading.Forms.Droid.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/FFImageLoading.Platform.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/FormsViewGroup.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/HtmlAgilityPack.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Analytics.Android.Bindings.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Analytics.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Android.Bindings.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Crashes.Android.Bindings.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Crashes.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/ModernHttpClient.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Newtonsoft.Json.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/OkHttp.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Plugin.Connectivity.Abstractions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Plugin.Connectivity.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Plugin.CurrentActivity.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Plugin.Settings.Abstractions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Plugin.Settings.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Plugin.Share.Abstractions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Plugin.Share.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Remotion.Linq.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/SgmlReaderDll.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Splat.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/System.Collections.Immutable.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/System.Interactive.Async.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.Design.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/extrony.dll
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abdullah.extrony/files/.__override__/extrony.Data.dll
Loaded assembly: Mono.Android.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Java.Interop.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Runtime.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Collections.Concurrent.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Reflection.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Threading.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Collections.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Linq.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Reflection.Extensions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: MonoDroidConstructors [External]
Loaded assembly: System.ObjectModel.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Threading.Tasks.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Xml.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.IO.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Runtime.Extensions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Linq.Expressions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Globalization.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.ComponentModel.dll [External]
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #2
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #3
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #4
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #5
Loaded assembly: System.Linq.Queryable.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Data.Common.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.Data.dll [External]
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #6
Loaded assembly: System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll [External]
```

**EDIT 3:**
Tested on different devices per suggestion received via comments. These are the results (from a release build)

- ~8 to 10 seconds on Samsung Galaxy OnNXT
- ~6-7 seconds on Xiaomi Mi Max Prime
- ~4-5 seconds on Redmi Note 3
- ~9.5 seconds on Asus Zenfone2

**Edit 4:**
I have done a very detailed testing and I can confirm that "context.Migrate() and a simple query with SingleOrDefault()" (EFCore) takes 9 seconds. If I remove this call, the app starts in ~3 seconds.

**EDIT 5:**
I was expecting to do the db init on a different thread in the splash activity (like the below), since the Xamarin.Forms initialization (usually) takes around 3 seconds and I want the init also to happen in parallel. However it appears that even though it runs on a different thread the EFCore db init also contributes to the start-up time.
Am I doing anything wrong?

```
 protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();

        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
        {
            App.DbFolder = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            App.InitializeDb();
        });

        StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));

    }
```

Any help with a suggestion?

Comment: Are you running on emulator or on real device?

Comment: Not sure, why this question is down voted. Please let me know and I can remove if it is really a bad question.

Comment: You might try sharing the startup code as part of the question. You might also try commenting out certain startup steps to see if the time is reduced, and include those findings too. This way the question meets the tests of shows code and attempt to self-solve. Meanwhile, 8 seconds seems pretty normal to start the app in debug mode and have the debugger attach, but would be quite long for a release build launched from the device apps page.

Comment: Okay. I actually attached the log and thought the log gives full info. Apart from using those libraries I don't have any other expensive operations happening on the first page. Thought the log I gave for debug mode, a release build running on a mobile takes 8 seconds too. If it's not normal I will try re-creating this in a sample app.

Comment: What version of Forms? The latest pre-release has some startup time improvements.

Comment: Also, what linker settings do you have for release builds? The more aggressive the linker, the smaller the app and faster the startup time.

Comment: I am using Xamarin.Forms 2.3.4.214-pre5. I use "SDK Only" option for linker, because taking "SDK & User Assemblies" crashes the app. Also Proguard is enabled. App size comes around ~24MB. Here is my [app size question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43131308/xamarin-apk-app-size/43142895#43142895)

Comment: Are you using xamarin insight?  I recently recognized xamarin insight takes so much space memory and time to load. It reduced my startup time to half after removing it. Not sure about hockeyapp or mobile center

Answer (score 4):

4.5 Seconds is being taken up by this section, if this is an accurate representation of when the app finishes loading.

```
04-01 07:53:15.443 D/Mono    ( 1742): [0x9ac5e930] hill climbing, change max number of threads 2
04-01 07:53:15.445 W/art     ( 1742): JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for md54ada4fbe4a5955f6151fa282d30cfc48.SelfDisposingBitmapDrawable
Resolved pending breakpoint at 'CleanUpReceiver.cs:16,1' to void extrony.Droid.Receivers.CleanUpReceiver.OnReceive (Android.Content.Context context, Android.Content.Intent intent) [0x00000].
04-01 07:53:20.059 D/Mono    ( 1742): DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/libsqlite.so' ('/system/lib/libsqlite.so').
04-01 07:53:20.059 D/Mono    ( 1742): Searching for 'sqlite3_column_count'.
```

Everything is loaded at this point, hence it's something in your code, most likely in the App.xaml.cs constructor. I notice you also have EF Core as well.

There could be many things going on here, but until App.xaml.cs is completed, it will still show the splashscreen.

I would recommend adding a StopWatch in parts of your code on startup and see what is taking the time. From there you could ask a different question in stackoverflow relating that problem.

```
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch s = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
s.Start();

// Code in here

s.Stop();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Elapsed Time: {s.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString("N0")}");
```

Comment: Great direction.  Thank you! I will try that and come back with my findings.

Comment: Just FYI. It actually takes 10 seconds. Not sure, why I typed 8. I tested again multiple times. Updated my question as well. Trying with what Adam advised with.

Comment: Thank you Adam. While testing observed one more thing. Please see my EDIT2. Any clue?

Comment: I noticed you mentioned you loaded ProGuard. Does the startup time improve if you uncheck proguard. You can also test if you uncheck or check shared runtime.

Comment: Switching ProGuard or Shared runtime On or Off doesn't seem to have any impact. Also the timing is same in both Debug & Release. This takes too long only on the real device but the emulator looks to be faster (see EDIT2 in my question). Any idea what are those "Loaded Assembly ...." messages I get only on the device?

Comment: Do you have Internal Only or Prefer Internal selected in your properties. Maybe its a slow flash drive pulling from external

Comment: It was "Prefer Internal". I tested with "Internal Only" as well as "Prefer External"
No difference with "Internal Only". However "Prefer External" takes ~15 to ~20seconds (sad face).

Comment: How long does it take for a blank Xamarin Forms Android app to load on this device?

Comment: A blank Xamarin.Forms app on a device takes ~4.5seconds in debug mode and ~3.8seconds in release

Comment: I mean on my device

Comment: I upgraded all the projects to Xamarin.Forms to 2.3.4 (latest) and I can consistently see the startup time on the  emulator (VS emulator running API 23) is 2.5 seconds. However on a device it still takes ~11 seconds. My stopwatch indicates (Thanks to Adam for the tip) that EntityFramework db initialization (including db.Migrate() and a simple query) takes ~9 seconds and the rest takes ~2 seconds ONLY ON DEVICE. Not sure how emulator running faster? Is this a problem with only my device model Asus Zenfone2? Should I report this? Any input/help please?

Comment: Can you test on a different device? Just to confirm it is specifically that device/model.

Comment: Sure. I don't have another android device currently, but will get a couple soon. I will come back with my findings.

Comment: Hey again, tested on multiple devices please see Edit3 on the question.

Comment: Any input from anyone please? Should it be reported on the EF core repo? Does any one similar issue who use EF Core on Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: Is it only EFCore that causes the issue. Does loading other packages cause issues?

Comment: I guess so. It looks like only ef Migrate() and a simple db query takes around ~9 seconds (one of my comments above). Not sure if somebody else feels the same though!

Comment: Please see my Edit 4

Comment: My suggestion with Edit4 is it sounds like it is creating the database, or doing extensive checks. Is it the migrate that does it, or the SingleOrDefault?

Comment: It is Migrate() that takes ~6 seconds (in debug) ~4 seconds with Ctrl+F5. (SingleOrDefault takes ~3 in debug & ~1.5 with Ctrl+F5). I have only three tables, however should it create the tables only for the first time when the app runs on a device? My numerous tests reveal that "Migrate()" takes this much time consistently even for all the runs. Do you feel it may be an optimization opportunity at EF Core side? Any other thoughts? (I am currently splitting and differing the db inits/calls to avoid start-up delay, by introducing a "Welcome Page")

Comment: Looks like its narrowed down to the Migrate option. The only options from here on would be to either lodge an issue on GitHub for EFCore, though you may not get any response, or it may take a long time for a response. The 2nd option will be to download the EFCore source into your app, and debug it yourself, finding the exact line or lines that are causing the delay. Submitting GitHub issue with that information will yield a much better response and lead to a fix quicker. Or maybe even a temporary workaround.

Comment: Thank you Adam. I will start doing just that. I will come back with an update sooner.

Comment: Please see my Edit 5

Answer (score -1):

If your Main Page calls services , loads data or does something that needs some time to complete, you can add splash screen . This is solve my problem on android.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/oussamaalrifai/xamarin-forms-android-workaround-for-splash-screen-with-lo/

Comment: I did that already as you can see in my question. Thanks for the link though.