# How to reduce App Size in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have developed one App and build APK and IPA for Ad-Hoc testing in Xamarin Forms PCL Project.

Now, Android Size App is 76.5 MB while Iphone App Size is just 34.5 MB. Why?

What are the reason behind this major App size Difference?

Thank You.

Comment: I think there is a lot written on this already, for instance here: https://xamarinhelp.com/reducing-app-file-size-xamarin-forms/ what have you tried? Where did you fail? Please have a look at how to [ask a proper question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Yes, before asking a question in Stackoverflow, we gotta search the Internet  first and only if we didn't find something useful should we ask here. Apart from @Gerald's links, here is another link for Android:
[How To Keep Your Android App Size Down](https://montemagno.com/how-to-keep-your-android-app-size-down/)

Comment: About the difference between Android and iOS app's file size, I guess the reason is that on the android injects one lib for each supported architecture in a single apk file. You'll see that if you choose at the android project's properties to _'generate one package per selected ABI'_ the difference will be not too huge.

Comment: @Vahid I agree with you, but I think it's interesting to have one good reference about this topic here on SO if there's no duplicate of it. The way this platform simplifies the search and target objective answers to this kind of thing (and as short as possible) is very useful.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza, I have tried that but still there is a same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use link libraries option to reduce file size

https://montemagno.com/how-to-keep-your-android-app-size-down/
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43142895/9326622

Comment: Thanks. It works fine, but When I have installed app and start it just stop automatically. It gives popup like, "Unfortunately,
 {AppName} has stopped working." Why this is happening?

Comment: Please find Screenshot using this Link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/17LvNisBR0r4bS3eBhd98d9OitXPJmKFT/view?usp=sharing

Comment: no i mean debug error message.
didnt you debug that error?

Comment: without seeing the code behind nothing i can do. i think unhandled exception  occurs in somewhere. put try catch to all functions in your opening page try to get exception message

Comment: But If I am using Linking as "None", It works perfectly. When I have changes Linking "User and SDK assembly" and build new APK, it will gives this error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165205/discussion-between-supun-liyanaarachchi-and-srusti-thakkar).

Answer (score 0):

You can enable Application App bundles (.aab). It will reduce your application size even more once deployed through the Google Play store.

To enable it, look in your *.Droid.csproj properties

[image: csproj options]

This [xamarin blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/android-app-bundle/) is a good reference.