# I am getting error in building xamarin android project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

> The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
>   Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method:
>   'Android.Views.ScaleGestureDetector
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.GestureManager::InitializeScaleDetector()'
>   in assembly: 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.dll' --->
>   Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Void
>   Android.Support.V4.View.ScaleGestureDetectorCompat::SetQuickScaleEnabled(Android.Views.ScaleGestureDetector,System.Boolean)
>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedMethod(MethodReference
>   reference) at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference
>   reference) at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction
>   instruction)

Comment: [set linking to none](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/146012/error-during-release-build)

Comment: Actually the app size is 114 MB and I want to reduce it to approx 30 MB. It is perfectly work when linking is none but i want to set the linking to sdk and user assembly for reducing the app size.Or if any other idea to reduce the app size so please suggest.

Comment: Right click project ===>choose `Properties`===>choose `Android Options`,Changing `Linking` properties from "SDK Assemblies only" to "None" and it worked in my case.https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUv3u.png

Comment: If you have done that, have a try with this link.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43131308/xamarin-apk-app-size/43142895#43142895 And `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.dlll` was referred from a different location in the android project references.You need to change that.

Comment: I have tried both the options but it doesn't work for me. When Linking is set to none then it works fine but when we changed then this problem occur.And when linking is none then app is so heavy approx 115MB.

Comment: This problem is come due to "Android.Views.ScaleGestureDetector "

Comment: I update an answer for reference.If be helpfu, thanks for marking it in advance.^.^

Comment: I saw a lot of issues related to linking so I never use it and always set it to "None"

Answer (score 0):

> 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException:

Sometimes it is resulted from `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.dll` location refer from different place in the android project references.You need to change it.Here is a similar discussion about how to solve this problem.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/102599/the-linkassemblies-task-failed-unexpectedly-error-while-building-the-application

In addition, you can check the sdk version, set the **target sdk version** to a newer version, and try again.

[image]